# Adding a deleted object back to realm fails swift

Tags: swift, realm

I added an object to realm and was able to delete the objecct, however if I try readding the object back again I get this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'Attempting to create an object of type 'PropertyImage' with an
>   existing primary key value '3'.

item with key 3 was deleted and when I viewed the realmDB and the item with key 3 does not exist. how do I get this over with.

below is how I add to my db and how I delete

```
func delete<T: Object>(_ object: T, title: String) where T: Codable {
        do {
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title=%@", title)
            guard let toRemove = realm?.objects(T.self).filter(predicate) else { return}
            try realm?.write {
                realm?.delete(toRemove)
            }
        } catch {
        }
    }

    func create<T: Object>(_ objects: [T]) where T: Codable {
        do {
            try realm?.write {
                realm?.add(objects)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

adding is done like this

`var property: FeaturedProperties?`
`RealmManager.instance.create(property)`

deleting is

`RealmManager.instance.delete(property, title: property.title!)`

Comment: where your creation code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a messy creation then do this to avoid same primary key insertion

```
do { 
    // property to be saved 
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "primaryProperty=%d",property.primaryProperty)
    guard let arr = realm?.objects(T.self).filter(predicate) , arr.isEmpty else { print("exists") ; return }    
    // call create here 
} catch {
      print(error)
}
```

where `primaryProperty` is the primary value in your model

Comment: is the creation messy? and where does this code enter?

Comment: before calling `RealmManager.instance.create(property)`

Comment: primaryProperty which is id?

Comment: the id is an Int

Comment: moreover, this would not allow me add that same object even after deleting

Comment: you delete with title which isn't the primary key , so probability of this crash is high

Comment: If I try deleting with primary key, I get a crash similar to this `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3)`

Comment: replace `%@" `with `%d"`